# Ideal data source for Standalone Applications?

Tags: java, ms-access, database

Suppose I created a standalone application in java and distributed it through my website.

What I need to know is what is the ideal Database solution I can use so that all the users can use the application without installing anything extra.

For example, if I use SQL server or MySql database, the downloader will need those installed so that I can dump my database on it. Another solution I see is to use Database file like Microsoft Access .mdb file. But that too will need Microsoft Office installed on the client. XML files are platform independent but anyone can open and change them.

What is the solution used by most of the applications?

Comment: check out [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is a very potent candidate for your need. We use it as a default RDBMS in all our demo applications and also for db-driven unit testing.

Comment: H2 looks really interesting. It also offers ODBC driver. Thats good. Thanks.

Comment: It also has a very reasonable standard SQL support, which makes it convenient to switch between different RDBMSes if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an embedded database.  There are hundreds for Java some which use SQL and many which don't.  Any database you use, you may want the users to be able to maintain, so users editing the data may be a good thing.

You could consider Derby as it ships with Java.

I would use plain flat files which are CSV formatted unless you have a more specific requirement. e.g. you can load and edit them in excel/spreadsheet editor/text editor.

Answer (score 2):

[H2](http://www.h2database.com) is the successor of [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org) (same developer). It is not only one of the finest embedded DBs for JAVA, it is also free, even for commercial use. It's great with hibernate and comes with with a powerful web-interface (you can start it by running the h2 jar file). Additionally there is the possibility to encrypt you database (AES). We use that feature for getting some security aspects right with some of our projects.

Comment: Yes and interestingly, it also supports large Objects. Really cool.

Answer (score 1):

check javadb. it is easy and can be redistributed

Answer (score 0):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) can do this : there is an embedded version.

There is some good [java drivers](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/)

Answer (score 0):

Using MDB files on Windows doesn't require any additional installation requirements such as Microsoft Office.  DAO and ADO have come with the Windows OS since Windows 2000.

Comment: But it does limit your app to being used by Windows users.

Comment: The original question mentioned SQL Server or MySQL, so multiple platforms were at least potentially contemplated with MySQL.